# learning plsql in sqldeveloper

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I just started to learn PLSQL. I had only SQLDEVELOPER  to access Oracle Database.

When I run following code:

```
DECLARE 
  title VARCHAR(8);
  salary NUMBER;
BEGIN
  title := 'DBA';
  salary := 50000;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Job Title: '|| title);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Expected Salary'|| TO_CHAR(salary));
END;
/
```

I get the output `"anonymous block completed"`.

Also, On running the command "set serveroutput on", I get a blank output.

I had other option is to download oracle database express edition and install on the local system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Developer there is a menu option `View -> Dbms output` which you need to follow to set the serveroutput on for your database connection.

Once done, you will see the DBMS Output window pane, you then need to click the green plus `"+"` icon to enable serveroutput for your connection.

Other than that, you haven't asked a specific question....

Answer (score 0):

put just above this line of code :

`SET SERVEROUTPUT ON`